# Swift 3. How properly insert variable instead star sign in "//*"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Sorry, there is such code:

```
if let removedElementName = runCommand.value {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") {
        node, stop in node.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

How properly insert variable **removedElementName** instead star sign in "**//***"

Comment: You want to remove all the children with a given `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove every child with a given name you can write

```
self.children
    .filter { $0.name == "nameToRemove" }
    .forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
```